# How to convert &amp to & in RDLC when it returns from database

Tags: sql, reporting-services, rdlc

I have data returned from the database.
The user enter data & data & data etc.
when I call it from the database into my RDLC report it returns &amp instead of &. It seems converted.

Here's Screenshot of what I mean.
[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q45o.jpg)

Comment: Check this related post https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fbd2b1bc-8806-41ca-94ea-df79ea06beb4/sql-report-builder-30-ampersand-displays-as-ampamp-for-company-name?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: @niktrs Perfect! Thanks